# how to add local file based printer port in command line

Tags: windows, command-line, printing, printer

I can add a local file based printer port using the printer properties->Ports screen in Windows 10.

[Adding local file based printer port in printer properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKSzx.png)

But I need to add a new printer with file based local printer port in command line.

I have tried both:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "testprinter1" /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /r "C:\util\test.pdf" /m "Microsoft Print To PDF"
```

and

```
Cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs -a -p "testprinter1" -m "Microsoft Print To PDF" -r "C:\util\test.pdf"
```

But both are giving 'The specified port is unknown.'  error and not add the virtual printer.

I have looked [prnport.vbs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc754352(v=ws.11)) to add a local printer port, but this prnport.vbs is written for adding/managing tcp/ip based printer ports.

I need to know is there a way to add a local file based printer port in command line.

Comment: Have you tried first connecting to lpt1: with /r, and then changing it with PortName "C:\util\test.pdf"? See https://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php

Comment: I have tried. It adds the printer but changing PortName with 'rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "testprinter1" PortName "C:\util\test.pdf"'  gives 'The arguments are invalid.' error.    Apparently it waits an existing port with name 'C:\util\test.pdf'